# Run two python file with infinity loop in another python file

Tags: python, multithreading, multitasking, keylogger

I have two python files, one for listening to the keyboard and another for mouse, each of these two files have a listener which are an infinite loop. when I want to call these two files from my main.py it just runs the first one.

Keyboard Listener

```python
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
   print(key)

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Mouse Listener

```python
from pynput.mouse import Listener

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):       
    print(button)

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Main

```python
import KeyboardL
import MouseL
```

I also tried to run it by os.system('python MouseL.py & KeyboardL.py &') but it still just could run the first one.
Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use either separate threads or subprocesses, so it doesn't block the main process.

Threading: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Subprocesses: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html